# Index on ts field in oplog.rs is not updated

Tags: mongodb

I have an application that reads the oplog.rs collection in a mongodb 2.2 replica set by querying on the ts field.

I added an index on the ts field, but it doesn't get updated when new entries are inserted into the oplog.

What am I missing? I can't find anything in the mongodb docs about indexes on capped collections are not supported (rather the opposite), and I can't find any info about the oplog being special.

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining that the index isn't updated appropriately?

Comment: I combine info by reading oplog entries in natural (insert) order with reads using the ts field. When new data has been inserted I get inconsistent results. If I manually update the ts index I get correct results.

Comment: And you're reading oplog entries with a tailed cursor or a normal one?

Comment: Yes, the find on ts is using a tailored cursor.

Comment: For clarification, when I remove the index on ts everything work as expected.

Comment: If you use a tailable cursor you wont necessarily see new entries. A tailable cursor always returns documents in natural order. If your new entries are lower in natural order than the current tail it will never be returned. That's the whole usecase for tailable cursors. You will have to use normal cursors if you want this to work.

Comment: Without an index the natural order for a cursor on ts is always insert order. With an index it changes because that would be based on the b-tree walk order. Basically the approach isn't valid ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've discovered, secondary indexes are not supported on system collections such as `local.oplog.rs` and `*.system.profile`. In MongoDB 2.4 and older the indexes would appear to have been created, but were never actually updated. Newer versions of MongoDB (2.6+) return an error if you try to directly update a system collection with an unsupported change such as attempting to create additional indexes.

The `oplog.rs` collection is definitely "special" because its intended use is only for replication. The replication internals make some assumptions about expected operations for the oplog on this basis. For example, replication only needs to insert oplog entries  -- unlike a capped collection that you may create yourself, oplog entries are *never* updated.

Applications are expected to read the oplog with a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) if they need to follow new entries that are inserted into the oplog, or to do a find using [`$natural` order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order).

The [tailable cursor tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) goes into some more detail on usage, but a few particular points to note are:

> - Tailable cursors do not use indexes and return documents in natural order.
> - Because tailable cursors do not use indexes, the initial scan for the query may be expensive; but, after initially exhausting the cursor, subsequent retrievals of the newly added documents are inexpensive

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing? I can't find anything in the mongodb docs about indexes on capped collections are not supported (rather the opposite), and I can't find any info about the oplog being special.

Your question is a litle vague as to exactly how you are going about your current implementation. However, it seems that it is not that the index is not updated but rather you are not notified of updates because MongoDB has no pub/sub feature yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3385

You could use a tailable cursor on this collection ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/ ) to actually get updates over a prolonged time.

Comment: The app occasionally reads from the oplog by querying on the ts field, and it gets outdated results back. When I manually re-index it works as expected.

Comment: @Sammaye: FYI, the issue is in fact that `oplog.rs` is a "special" capped collection intended to only be used for replication. The replication internals do a fast insert which ignores indexes (since none are expected/needed for normal replication and tailable cursors). As at MongoDB 2.4, the extra indexes will not be updated.  Future support for PubSub or tailable cursors using an index may change that.

Comment: @Stennie That's something to mention in the docs cos I have just fully finished reading all of the replication part and I couldn't find mention that inserts into the oplog ignore index building.

Comment: Agreed, though not sure where exactly in the manual that belongs. Modifying any of the system collections isn't recommended, unless you are following a documented procedure such as resizing the oplog. Any suggestions on where you would look for the warnings?

Comment: @Stennie That is indeed a difficult question though: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/#oplog-internals might work?

Comment: @Stennie But then it is odd because following on the links in that section actually take you to a section labelled resizing the oplog which has a much better explanation and maybe it would fit better: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-oplog-sizing edit, seems that link might be a bug, the real link is: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#oplog

Comment: Thanks .. probably needs to be noted in both places, but can be done as an include.