# mongodump oplog, backup a single database

Tags: mongodb

I want to create an incremental backup strategy from a single database using oplog

since the --oplog option from mongodump creates a dump of full version, I wonder if there is any way to:

1. make a dump from a **single database** **using the oplog option** from "x" seconds ago?
2. make a dump from a **single collection** **using the oplog option** from "x" seconds ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since the --oplog version from mongodump creates a dump of full version

Actually, `mongodump --oplog` creates a [partial dump of the `oplog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--oplog) that only contains operations from the duration of the `mongodump` operation. The purpose of this option is to capture an effective point-in-time state of the database, as otherwise write operations during the `mongodump` procedure can affect the output of the backup.

> make a dump from a single database using the oplog option from "x" seconds ago?
>
> make a dump from a single collection using the oplog option from "x" seconds ago?

You can't use the oplog to dump a database or collection snapshot from X seconds ago:

- In order for the oplog to be usefully applied in a restore procedure, the oplog has to have an entry in common with your last full backup.
- You can't efficiently dump a subset of the `oplog` as there are no indexes (and the oplog is a special-use capped collection that does not support adding indexes).

#### Backup Strategy

Your backup strategy using the oplog would be:

- create periodic full backup of your database
- periodically backup the full oplog

You can use the oplog to do a point-in-time restore, but it's not very effective as an incremental backup strategy since you have to backup the full oplog.

If you want to incrementally backup a single collection, you could potentially do so using `mongodump` and a "last updated field" (or for an insert-only collection, a "created" timestamp).

A more common way to achieve a quick point in time backup for a replica set is using a [filesystem snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/). Depending on your underlying storage layer, filesystem snapshots can generally be completed quickly with efficient storage of changes between successive snapshots. Snapshots are local, so you still have to consider how you will export backups offsite as part of your overall strategy.

#### Caveats of `mongodump` for backup

When you use [`mongodump` to backup](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/) you should also be aware that this:

- Requires reading all data, so may swap useful data out of memory if your data set is much larger than memory.
- Exports the full data (except the `local` database, which includes the oplog), but only the definitions for indexes.
- The `mongodump` backup will use the least space (since you don't have preallocated storage or indexes) but will also have the longest time to restore (since `mongorestore` will have to rebuild all the data files and indexes).

Related questions:

- [Modify and replay the oplog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog)
- [Index on `ts` field in `oplog.rs` is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389325/index-on-ts-field-in-oplog-rs-is-not-updated)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try the snapshot method next

Comment: @Stennie Thats a great answer !!

Comment: Hi Stennie. I am seeing your profile just found that you work for mongodb. So I have a question can you please answer. **Que ->** Why there is is no operator in aggregation which founds the duplicates inside the array? You can see my [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839656/find-duplicate-inside-array-without-unwind). The people have answered that question but it's tricky one for that normal question. So could you please let me know if you are taking any steps towards it!!!