# Find duplicate inside array without $unwind

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have below users collection

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "adds": ["111", "222", "333", "111"]
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "adds": ["555", "666", "777", "555"]
}, {
    "_id": 3,
    "adds": ["888", "999", "000", "888"]
}]
```

I need to find the duplicates inside the `adds` array

The expected output should be

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "adds": ["111"]
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "adds": [ "555"]
}, {
    "_id": 3,
    "adds": ["888"]
}]
```

I have tried using many operators `$setUnion`, `$setDifference` but none of the did the trick.

**Please help!!!**

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `$unwind`? An $unwind/$group/$match/$project would be a straightforward approach to compare with the answers posted so far. Also, what specific version of MongoDB server are you using?

Comment: @Stennie I am using mongodb **4.0** the latest one. Because `$unwind` makes some performance issue. Find duplicates inside an array is not a big deal. There should be some aggregation operator for that? Isn't it? BTW thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Stennie Any comments? **;-)**

Comment: As at MongoDB 4.0 there isn't a shorthand aggregation operator for filtering an array to only find duplicates. There are several different approaches to achieve this outcome using existing operators, but you'd have to benchmark to compare performance for your use case. If this is a common need you might want to consider adjusting your data model to make it more efficient to query. For example, instead of having an array of values you could have an array of objects with counts which you increment when adding to the array: `[{"111": 2, "222": 1, "333": 1}]`.

Comment: You could also raise a feature suggestion for a new operator in the [MongoDB Jira issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) (project: "SERVER", component: "Aggregation Framework"). That's unlikely to help you in the short term, but if others are interested in the same feature it might land in a future release of MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you @Stennie I have opened one jira for this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) to generate arrays of numbers from `1` to `n` where `n` is the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of `adds`. Then you can "loop" through that numbers and check if `adds` at `index` ([$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html)) exists somewhere before `index` if yes then it should be considered as a duplicate. You can use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to check if element exists in array specifying 0 and `index` as search range.

Then you just need to use `$project` and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to replace indexes with actual elements. You can also add [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) to avoid duplicated duplicates in final result set.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            duplicates: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $range: [ 1, { $size: "$adds" } ] },
                    as: "index",
                    cond: {
                        $ne: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$adds", { $arrayElemAt: [ "$adds", "$$index" ]  }, 0, "$$index" ] }, -1 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            adds: {
                $setUnion: [ { $map: { input: "$duplicates", as: "d", in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$adds", "$$d" ] } } }, [] ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Prints:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "adds" : [ "111" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "adds" : [ "555" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "adds" : [ "888" ] }
```

Comment: great great great. Awesome mickl

Comment: @mickl - It appears to be not working when you multiple duplicate values. ex "adds": ["111", "222", "333","333", "111"]

Comment: Kindly note that you don't need the `$slice` since `$indexOfArray` supports the `startIndex`parameter. Also, the two stages `$addFields` and `$project` can be merged into one.

Comment: Modified my answer, thank you @dnickless, that makes it a bit shorter. I'll still keep two stages since I believe it's more readable than nested map/filter

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version that you might want to compare in terms of performance:

```
db.users.aggregate({
  $project:{
    "adds":{
      $reduce:{
        "input":{$range:[0,{$size:"$adds"}]}, // loop variable from 0 to max. index of $adds array
      //"input":{$range:[0,{$subtract:[{$size:"$adds"},1]}]}, // this would be enough but looks more complicated
        "initialValue":[],
        "in":{
            $let:{
              "vars":{
                "curr": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$adds", "$$this"] } // the element we're looking at
              },
              "in":{
                // if there is another identical element after the current one then we have a duplicate
                $cond:[
                  {$ne:[{$indexOfArray:["$adds","$$curr",{$add:["$$this",1]}]},-1]},
                  {$setUnion:["$$value",["$$curr"]]}, // combine duplicates found so far with new duplicate
                  "$$value" // continue with current value
                ]
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The logic is based on a loop variable which we get through the [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) operator. This loop variable allows for sequential access of the `adds` array. For every item that we look at, we check if there is another identical one *after* the current index. If yes, we have a duplicate, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation. The idea is to collect the distinct values and iterate over values and check if the value is present in `adds` array; if present keep the value else ignore the value.

```
db.users.aggregate({
  "$project":{
    "adds":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":{"$setUnion":["$adds",[]]},
        "initialValue":[],
        "in":{
          "$concatArrays":[
            "$$value",
            {"$let":{
              "vars":{
                "match":{
                  "$filter":{"input":"$adds","as":"a","cond":{"$eq":["$$a","$$this"]}}
                }},
                "in":{
                  "$cond":[{"$gt":[{"$size":"$$match"},1]},["$$this"],[]]
                }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This would probably be faster: `db.users.aggregate({
  "$project":{
    "adds":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":"$adds",
        "initialValue":[],
        "in":{
            "$let":{
              "vars":{
                "match":{
                  "$filter":{"input":"$adds","as":"a","cond":{"$eq":["$$a","$$this"]}}
                }},
                "in":{
                  "$cond":[{"$gt":[{"$size":"$$match"},1]},{"$setUnion":["$$value",["$$this"]]},"$$value"]
                }
            }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
})`